# I am encountering problems while using PyInstaller to package a Qt application that contains a spaCy language model

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

[image]

My Python version is 3.10.13, using a .venv environment. The spaCy model I load is zh_core_web_trf. The code runs normally in VSCode, but when I package it with PyInstaller, it shows an error. I have already packaged the model files and spaCy-related modules, and have also installed spacy-transform.

I have tried switching between Conda and venv environments, as well as including hidden imports in the .spec file, and changing the code from spacy.load(modelname) to modelname.load().

Comment: My system is macOS 14.1.1.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.